# Including date in Makefile

Tags: bash, makefile

I am writing a Makefile for a simple projects. The Makefile should produce the README.md of the project which should include a time & date make was run.
Here's what I've got so far:

```
README.md:dependent_file.sh
    now=$(date)
    echo "Generated on $now"
clean:
    rm *.md
```

For now, all I want my Makefile to do is append the current date to the README.md
My problem is that I cannot get the actual date-it coms up as blank.
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: In addition to the answer to the above question you will next run into the fact that each line in a makefile recipe is run in a different shell.  If you want shell variables to be available through multiple commands you need to put them into the same logical line; for example: `now=$$(date); echo "Generated on $$now"`

Answer (score 0):

Each line of a recipe is executed in a separate shell, so `now` is not defined in the shell that executes the `echo` statement. You can use line continuations to join multiple physical lines into a single *logical* line.

```
README.md: dependent_file.sh
        now=$$(date) \
        echo "Generated on $$now"
```

or use a semicolon to combine both commands on a single line.

```
    README.md: dependent_file.sh
        now=$$(date); echo "Generated on $$now"
```

In both cases, you'll have to use `$$` to prevent any expansions from happening in the Makefile before the recipes are executed.